# Correct way to rewrite sync function with TAP

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

it might be a stupid question. I am rewriting a synchronous HTTP send data function to asynchronous with TAP.
The function looks like this:

```
public void SendToUrl(string url, string content)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] payload = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/plain";
        request.ContentLength = payload.Length;

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            sw.Stop();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                ....
            }
            else
            {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
    catch // error handling omitted
    {
    }
}
```

At first, I think it is very straightforward, just replace all sync .NET library functions with their awaitable XXXAsync counterparts and change function signature to `public async void SendToUrlAsync(...)` (because I use await inside the function), however, after having read some articles, it looks like lots of people say `async void` is not safe (could crash whole process), and it is designed for event handler only. Synchronous void function should be translated into `async Task`, even I do want a fire-and-forgot function here. 
If that is true, to forcibly return a Task, I need to encapsulate whole code within a `Task.Run(() => {...})` which looks like redundant and odd to me since I really don't care about the return Task object, but if I don't await it compiler will complain.
So, in my case, what is the recommended way to rewrite it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> replace all sync .NET library functions with their awaitable XXXAsync counterparts and change function signature

Actually, if you slightly modify the steps here, it's a bit simpler:

1. Replace all sync APIs with their `*Async` equivalents.
2. `await` them.

The compiler will the give you an error *suggesting* the correct signature for you (in this case, `async Task`).

> to forcibly return a Task, I need to encapsulate whole code within a Task.Run

Not at all. The `async` keyword will create a `Task` for you.

On a side note, the `Write` call is unsafe - it is possible for streams (network streams in particular) to only write a partial buffer.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Your book and your blog are super helpful. I followed your suggestions and found that your are right, with async keyword in signature I don't need to explicitly call Task.Run to create and return a task, happy to learn that. I have 2 questions : (1) Now compiler complains that I should await my new function SendToUrlAsync, if I do want fire-and-forget behavior, what should I do? (2) Could you explain a little bit more about Stream.Write/Stream.WriteAsync? I saw lots of samples that use request stream in this way, if it is not correct, what is the correct way to post data? Tks!

Comment: I tried to add await when caller called SendToUrlAsync, now compiler said I needed to change the caller to async Task. I can see that soon I need to change every function in this call chain to async Task, is that a good way?

Comment: @codewarrior: Ideally yes, you should let `async` grow. 1) To do fire-and-forget (which is [almost always wrong](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)), do `var _ = SendToUrlAsync();`. 2) Use `BinaryWriter` or put it in a `MemoryStream` and call `CopyToAsync`.